# Redistribution of List & Label

Tags: c#, software-distribution, listlabel

I tried to ship my application (C#, List & Label 23) to the customer's site. Everything works on my PC. I have copied all DLLs from my bin folder (where it works) to the customer. I'm getting an exception there that says "cmll23.dll is missing". But why does it work on my machine then (where I don't need this DLL, I've only cxll23.dll in my "bin" folder)? My code is simply

```
using (ListLabel LL = new ListLabel()) // this is the line where the exception happens
{
  …
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are using a 3rd party component. This Dll must be copied as well to the client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you've compiled your application on "AnyCPU". In this case, you need to ship both flavors of the unmanaged DLLs, x64 and x86. The only difference in the name is the prefix cx (x64) vs. cm (x86). Your customer seems to run a x86 OS - thus the requirement for x86 DLLs.

Check the "Redistributable Files" documentation or - even simpler - use the redistribution assistant for an easier deployment.